# R - should I name a variable or source it from a different dataframe directly?

Tags: r, performance, variables

I have a dataframe (df) with many factors that will be used in different equations in a loop. I am wondering which is the best (meaning "faster" or more "performatic") option: define each factor as a variable and then use the variable or source it directly.

Example below (for demo purposes, not real values)

```
df <- data.frame(factor = c(Test1, Test2, Test3),
                    value = c(1,2,3)
```

Option 1 (define variable and then use it)

```
x <- df %>% filter(factor == “Test1”) %>% select(value)

y = 2*x
```

Option 2 (source variable in the equation)

```
y = 2 * df %>% filter(factor == “Test1”) %>% select(value)
```

The variables will be used in a loop, so if option 1 is the most performatic, it would be best to define all variables before the loop, correct?

Comment: I think it's mostly style. My first concern was that order of operations would render your last code block bad (in case `2*df` was executed first ... it could fail), but the order of ops is fine for that ... but it still looks wrong to me. But again, *style*. Do what you like to read and what makes sense. If anybody else looks at your code, consider readability and maintainability. Frankly, is there a reason you don't just do `df$value[df$factor == "Test1"] * 2`?

Comment: Thanks - I am used to using dplyr, so that is why I wrote the code this way. Honestly, I didn't know about the base R option. I want other members of the team to read the code and understand it.

Comment: @r2evans just want to say thanks for the suggestion of using `df$value[df$factor == "Test1"] * 2`. I did some tests here and it works fine (and better) than the previous approach